# Leaflet.js strange borders

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to use a Leaflet.js library on my website, but when I'm copying code from Leaflet's Quick Start, I get something like this : [image: Leaflet map:]

and my code is:

```js
var myMap = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1Ijoib3N0cnl1c2VyIiwiYSI6ImNqdWt6bjZwMTBlNXo0MW9tYXo5cm1vYzgifQ.gI8BNI3q8ZPu55QgCkVzOQ'
}).addTo(myMap);
```

I have also added a height in css.
How can I remove this borders and have a clean map?

Comment: Welcome! It seems to be only part of the code. Can you create a [working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/863110) example so we could try to debug it?

Comment: That's not your code - the image shows the default OpenStreetMap tiles, whereas the code refers to the Mapbox Streets style (yes, I can tell them apart visually). If you expect people to help you, at least provide accurate information (please).

Comment: ...that (tiles style) and the attribution text is different as well.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Seems like you tried styling your map container with a CSS selector which is too generic, like:

```css
div {
  width: 80%;
  height: 35%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Therefore it interferes with Leaflet internal elements: corner `<div>`'s and controls (zoom and attribution) inherit these rules. Their size is deformed, and they get that extra border.

The easy solution is simply to make your CSS selector more specific, typically `#mapContainerId` instead of just `div`.